# Why sum(//*) returns this answer on this xml?

Tags: xpath

This is the xml

```
<a><b>2</b><c>3</c></a>
```

And this is the XPath query

```
sum(//*)
```

Which produces the following result :

```
Type: Num
Value : 28.0000
```

This is XPath 1.0
Please explain the type conversions (step by step)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's break it down:

- the `//*` would match the `a`, `b` and `c` nodes
- the [`sum()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/sum) would sum up the results of `number()` function call for every node
- the [`number()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/number) would call [`string()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/string) on every matching node
- the result of `number()` for "a" is 23, for "b" is 2, for "c" is 3 - `23+2+3=28`